# set as featured image not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a `wordpress site` with nexus theme. I have created a blog page which shows the posts.

When I add a new post and click on `set as featured image` or `add media` then I got nothing except and error in console .

```
TypeError: _.omit is not a function
http://xyz.com/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=admin-bar,hoverIntent,common,schedule,wp-ajax-response,autosave,suggest,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,post,backbone,media-models&load%5B%5D=,wp-plupload,media-views,media-editor,jquery-ui-position,wp-pointer,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,word-count,editor,quic&load%5B%5D=ktags,jquery-ui-resizable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-button,jquery-ui-dialog,wpdialogs,wplink,wpdialogs-popup,wp-fullscreen&ver=3.5.1
Line 89
```

Can anyone help me please how can I resolve this problem

every thing is working fine on my `localhost`

**Edit** :

Also when I am clicking on `add media` at top of the editor, I am getting the same problem

Comment: try  again after deactivating the jquery plugin or other unnessasary plugins or all the plugins one by one  many time its due to jquery confliction

Comment: I have no plugin activated rightnow, I have installed fresh wordpress and upload the theme from localhost to wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Add `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');` in functions.php.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks for the policing but I know how to use the site. The above *IS* my answer, I just phrased it as a question. I will edit out the question mark just to make *YOU* happy.

Comment: thanks to all, I got the solution as user850010, actually it was the problem of nexus theme

Comment: @CL75 I have added that thats why its running on localhost, besides that I am also getting same problem when I click on `add media`